# Promise return string value

Tags: typescript

I have this async function:

```
public promiseFunction = async (value: string): Promise<any> => {

        myFunction.send(data).then(() => {        
            return 'result from promise';
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return `Error string: ${error}`
        });
    }
```

Then i call this function of this way:

```
await promiseFunction('testing function')
          .then(function(val) {
            console.log(`result of function: ${val}`);
            reply(val);
          });
```

How can I return a value of a promise?

Answer (score 1):

Without really knowing what you are asking for and where and how you are using that function, I'd like to state
that you're probably using the [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax wrongly.

When using `await` you would normally do something like:

```
async function foo() {
  var result = await promiseFunction('testing function');
  console.log(result);
}
```